# What is an imaginary gauge potential?

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, gauge-theory, complex-numbers

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.02791) considers a generalised Strum-Liouville equation, that is equations of the form

$$
\left[-\frac{d}{dx}p(x)\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{i}{2}\left(\lambda_1(x)\frac{d}{dx}+\frac{d}{dx}\lambda_2(x)\right)+v(x)\right]\psi(x)=\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2\psi(x)\tag{1}
$$

and calls $\lambda_i(x)\in\mathbb{C}$ *complex gauge potentials*. What do these potentials represent physically?

In particular I'm interested in the case where $p(x)$ is constant and $v(x)=0$ so that $\psi(x)$ represents some kind of time harmonic wave equation.

Comment: Do you understand what a "gauge potential" is in the Hermitian case where $\lambda\in {\mathbb R}$?

Comment: No, not really..

Comment: It would be a good idea then to read up on the Schroedinger equation in a magnetic field.   In the one dimensional case in your  paper you can probably absorb the $\lambda$ into  the $\psi$ field by means of a gauge transformation. Again you will need to read a book on quantum mechanics to see how this works.